# how do i remove that small dot offset thingy that acts like the coordinate center

Tags: modeling

[image]

I'm trying to move this center piece onto the center of the base but this little dot is what goes to the coords i type in the box

Comment: turns out that was an origin point, and it was easy to move back to the center of the piece

Comment: this is the origin of your object, you can move it wherever you want, right click > Set Origin and choose Geometry if you want it to be at the center of the object, or choose the option you want

Comment: That dot is your friend and you should love to have it. That dot is the origin of the geometry, an is the point where the object rotates and is scaled. Instead of trying to get rid of it, learn how to use it to create your projects.